# SQL compare integers from column, output is wrong

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a SQL table on PHPMyAdmin with two columns that both contains integers (see image)

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Shcsl.png]

When the row is empty, the value is 'null'.
If I execute the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM `18-3-2019` WHERE `COL 13` < `COL 14`
```

I get the following result (left column is COL 13, right one is COL 14):

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgMmy.png]

The problem is that the statement isn't always true, for example the output 12 being smaller than 6. I see the relation between numbers higher then 10 being in the output as they are lower than the other number. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to `CAST` the string values (`VARCHAR`) to integers (`INT` / `SIGNED`).

```
SELECT '12' < '6'; -- 1
```

using `CAST(column AS SIGNED)` to compare the values:

```
SELECT 12 < 6; -- 0
SELECT CAST('12' AS SIGNED) < CAST('6' AS SIGNED); -- 0
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6b3c8d600de46e18d43c2ccaa1bdf567)

Comment: Thanks, it suddenly worked. I thought that I already tried that, but it now worked.